# C++ to simpler language (Python, Lua, etc) converter?

Tags: python, c++, code-translation

I know Python and I've come across a small C++ source file I would like to convert to Python. But the C++ code is too complex for me to understand without learning the language.

So I was wondering if there is a tool that does the opposite of what many people want: convert C++ code to Python, or another simpler language I could understand.
I know these tools work on very simple code and hardly do a perfect job even then, but the code I have *is* pretty small and simple.

I have found "ctopy", but there is no usage example, if I just pass a .cpp file to it, it just hangs, no error message or anything.
And maybe it won't work for C++ at all.
http://www.catb.org/~esr/ctopy/

Comment: what is your primary intent in achieving this? to _understand_ the code? to _use_ the code from Python?

Comment: I want to "port" the code to Python. Using automatic wrappers won't work, as I don't simply want to be able to use the code (which I already can anyway as there is a command-line exe available), but understand it and change it.

Comment: @user975135 - Guess you need to learn C++

Comment: @Ed Heal - That's not an answer to this question. An answer would be "there isn't any", but seems like you're not sure.

Comment: @user975135 - That is why it is a comment!

Comment: You cant say something does not exist unless you know everything in the world, but as far as I know, the answer is no

Comment: If you don't know what the code does (since you can't understand it), how would you tell if the conversion is correct?

Comment: There is https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/ to convert c++ to javascript if that suffices, however it's unlikely to build understandabe code.

Comment: If you understand programming, language is really a secondary thought centered around syntax. It, assuming you are well versed in Python, shouldn't be too complicated to learn a little C++ to get the job done.

Comment: You could also take the approach of asking yourself; "what does this source do in context of the program and how would I do that in Python?" Then, reverse engineer it. If you didn't know what it did there would be no reason to try to use it.

Comment: Of course ctopy doesn't work on C++; C++ is not C.  In any case, "This allows a human programmer to concentrate on the nontrivial parts of the translation." doesn't sound promising, since you'll need to learn the hard parts of C instead of the parts that are easy to learn.

Comment: So in order to learn C++ you want to transform the C++ code into Python code? Seriously, if the code is really that simple (and anything else will surely make any C++-to-Python translater explode, anyway), then your existing programming knowledge (since you say you understand Python) should definitely be enough. Everything you cannot grasp with your existing Python knowledge can't be understood by a C++-to-Python translator either. Of course I assume this is not just about syntax, which would be plain ridiculous.

Comment: Rewrite.  You're going from a relatively low-level language to a very high level language, with quite different approach to crucial things such as memory management.  Even if you could automate c++ syntax into python syntax, and that's a _huge_ if, the python would be some ridiculously unpythonic code that won't be any more understandable than the c++ code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Most translators produce inferior code which you can't really use anywhere; and the more complicated your code is, the worse the results are. Only real human brains can do that perfectly. I'd suggest that you learn the language. If you already know python, learning another language shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Fortunately, it is also possible to [automatically translate other programming languages to C++](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=%22to+c%2B%2B+(translator%7Ccompiler%7Cconverter%7Ctranspiler)%22) and [vice-versa](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=%22c%2B%2B+to+%2A+translator%7Cconverter%7Ccompiler%7Ctranspiler%22).

Comment: I won't downvote, but I know python pretty well and still have a very difficult time understanding C++... why? because C++ does MAJOR times more than python, such as pointers, pre-processing, along with other features, it's hard enough to simply understand the disgusting syntax of C++, but adding the extended featurability makes it a nightmare. and to comment, yes, software can do it too... it's all a matter of implementing human logic into the program, which isn't difficult... just EXTREMELY tedious.

Comment: @Tcll So you're saying C++ sucks because it has lots of features?

Comment: not at all, c++ is a great language (C is better for the major cross platform, not just the 3 os's), but it's difficult to understand, and has a disgusting syntax when compared to python.

Comment: Nonsense! A compiler could can grasp the code by definition. Just compile the C++ into whatever and then implement a generic bytecode virtual machine that you run on the block of whatever shit the compiler produced. Did we learn nothing from Emscripten it converts C++ to javascript and requires no brain.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen (and wanted) such a programming code converter and found exactly what you want in cpp2py although I personally haven't tried it for myself website https://github.com/hlamer/cpp2python

Comment: That script is a piece of junk.  It's just a bunch of regex substitutions!

Comment: Hey I said I haven't tried it yet for myself

Comment: Then saying it's exactly what was wanted is a bit of a stretch.  Thanks for the laugh though, anyone who wants a chuckle should check out that script!

Comment: @wim Don't be unfair. This script is pretty nice if you just needed what I did... A time saver to reformat some C++ snippits to python. Yes you have to know both languages to complete the task, so this doesn't help the OP, but for me, copying some Qt code for use in a python binding, it saved me a lot of tedious reformatting! Now I can just focus on making the code work, not replacing void with def, removing braces, adding ':', etc etc etc

Comment: Oh yeah thats ugly. Regex code convert?. 
Look a code coverter has another name, a compiler! And the thing with compilers, is compilers are hard (and fascinating too). The general approach is to basically tokenize it into a tree of some intermediate representation (eg an abstract syntax tree, llvm has some very interesting work in this field) then assemble the new code from that. 
This is more of a naive approach just trying to regex it into compliance and honestly? Ewww, code smells. It seems like the author just doesnt really know how. Points for trying I guess...

Comment: (following on from previous) which is to say a C++ to compiler is totally possible, but that approach is the WRONG way to do it.  A better approach would be to take the output of LLVMs IR code and write something that can output that code to Python. The added bonus is it would also compile almost any of the languages LLVM can compile (Most of them!) and turn them into python. UGLY python, but it'd be python.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little painful, but I have gotten some python code using

https://code.google.com/p/ctypesgen/

For some reason it doesn't handle `bool`'s.

It probably uses regex substitutions, and other things like that, but it sure beats writing out your own ctypes wrapper without it.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html

Another option you could look into, is compiling your C++ into an executable and then running the executable using python.

And if you decide you need the power of C/C++ in your tool belt:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973899/learning-c-java-coming-from-python

Hope that helps.

Comment: What does "compiling your C++ into an executable and then running the executable using python" even mean? The python interpreter does not read machine code, and even if it did it would not decide on equivalent python code to make the same thing happen, it would just pass the instructions on to the CPU....

Comment: There are functions for spawning a process.  win32process.CreateProcess , subprocess , etc. http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/win32process__CreateProcess_meth.html  You tell it what exe to launch and it does it.

Comment: your last link is now invalid

Comment: let's not forget, `_ctypes` scans dll files